# Is it good to insert or update record in multiple tables in single request in REST API?

Tags: php, rest, laravel

I am trying to build REST api using Laravel. 
My question, I want to update 2 models/tables in single rest api request. Is it good solution or I should have made 2 api calls, 1 for each model.

Note : I am not talking about multiple records in same model. I need to update multiple tables with 1 records in each.

Edit: 
In my case : Both models are related with each other. 
In modelA i am storing common data and according to a column value of `type` i need to decide modelB and store the data in modelB also.

Comment: @Veve : I have already mention that, Note : I am not talking about multiple records in same model. I need to update multiple tables with 1 records in each.

Comment: My mistake. I'll suggest to make 2 API calls, since the success of one insert/update doesn't mean the second will success, so you need to know the result of each operation.

Comment: Thanks @Veve: Can you please check Edit: part of my question. In my case both models are related.

Comment: From your edit, I'll use the API to insert/update modelA, and would use a trigger or a method in modelA responsible for the conditionnal insert/update for modelB. The API would then only return infos about modelA.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the specific case. If you have to make two separate API calls and the second one fails, this must not leave the database in an unstable state.

In your case it might be better to insert/update both tables with 1 request because the second model can't live on it's own and the fact that you have two tables is just an implementation detail that should remain hidden to the outside world.